# MS Project 2010 Custom Report with Gantt Chart

Tags: microsoft-project-2010, gantt

Is is possible using the custom report feature in MS Project 2010 to create a report that has both the Gantt Chart and the Cash Flow chart on the same report?
If it can't be done in MS Project does anyone know of another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not possible directly in Project.  You can certainly take a screen shot of the Gantt chart view (or use the Copy Picture command in Project).  Paste it an the Cash Flow chart from Excel into Word or PowerPoint.